# Google auth2 signIn promise not running in Safari, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, google-signin, google-oauth

The code shown below works in Chrome for logging in users, but not in Safari. In Safari, the Google login window pops up and allows me to select an account, but then never runs the code in the promise for signIn(). Totally stumped by this.

```
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    var gAuth = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: "myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    });

    $scope.loginGoogle = function() {

        gAuth.signIn().then(function(user, error) {

            // never reaches here in Safari, but works in Chrome

            if(error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {

                console.log('worked');
            }

        });

    }

});
```

Comment: The snippet doesn't properly catch the errors of the promise. You should handle it in the second parameter of the `then` function. Is there anything displayed in the console logs?

Comment: Weirdly the issue keeps going away and then coming back occasionally, but I haven't yet figured out why. I'll add the second parameter to the 'then' function, and then i'll be able to see if any errors come through if it goes wrong again. Thanks for your help!